# Если умрет родительский процесс, умрут ли дочерние?

Tags: php, многопоточность, unix

Есть PHP-демон, который запускается из консоли и делает много форков.

Если я в консоли введу ctrl+^c, что произойдет? Завершаться все дочерние процессы и родительский?

Comment: Вообще-то есть вариант чтобы этого не случилось (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553905/php-how-to-start-a-detached-process) НО там дергается не форк а exec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, завершится как родительский, так и дочерние процессы.